# Mysql C# Cannot connect to hosts but yet it can

Tags: c#, mysql

I would like to start out by saying as a community you all have the biggest help on the net. I have been coming here for years when I ran into issues, and 99% of them were resolved with your help. This current problem, is so strange, I can't seem to find an answer to it. So here I am, finally signed up and asking my own.

So here's the situation, I have a login form that calls MySQL and checks for username and password, and that works just fine, here is the connection code for it.

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=68.xx.xx.xxx;database=android;uid=myusername;pwd=mypass");
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT password FROM admin WHERE empid = " + textBox1.Text);

cmd.Connection = con;

con.Open();
```

So I can log in here just fine, and I can go about my business, I can open the new forms, and etc. When I get to the admin's control form where they want to send a GCM to a user I call this code.

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=68.xx.xx.xxx;database=android;uid=myusername;pwd=mypass");
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT gcm_regid FROM users WHERE empid = " + textBox1.Text);

cmd.Connection = con;

con.Open();
```

This part doesn't connect and gives me the error that it can not connect to any MySQL hosts.

So at this point, I have tried making new users, that didn't work either. It connects locally with no issues. This is a home built webserver running on WAMP so I have full access to make any changes I need to. I just don't know where to start since this just doesn't make sense.

BTW on another related note, myusername for logging in is set to Any Host with the %.

Thank you in advance for any and all help you can give me, this one has me puzzled.

EDIT: The connection strings are not on a new line, just the wrap around for the box is causing it. It is all 1 long line in Visual Studio Express. I just wanted to clarify that.

Comment: The connection object is disposable, so if you are opening it a second time without disposing of the initial object, this is going to cause issues, maybe wrap it in a using block when you want to use it?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I do close it and dispose of it. cmd.Connection.Close();
                           reader.Dispose();
                           cmd.Dispose();
                           close = false;
                           con.Close();

Comment: Not so much, just [use them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx), and the runtime will do all cleaning up neccessary on your behalf.

Comment: Just curious, my code works with local IPs, 192.... so if it's an issue with disposing, wouldn't I have the issue all the time, not just on external IPs?

Comment: BTW just tried it with usings around the connection strings, and that didn't resolve the issue =(

Comment: Just to remove any possibilities connected to permissions. Have you tried to connect to this remote host from your test PC using a  database manager of your choice?

Comment: No I haven't Steve can you elaborate what you mean? I have never used a manager system before :(.

Comment: To clarify, I use myphpadmin on local host with no problems. I use the default login with a password. I have tried using that as login in my code as well. If there is a better manager to test with I would be happy to do it. As I said I am stumped and willing to test and modify as much as needed.

Comment: Steve? Anyone else? This is still a problem, and I am still at a loss. Maybe tomorrow someone else can give me some guidance. Hope you all had a great Saturday! =)

Comment: For anyone having the same issue, I may have solved it. I will know more on Monday when I move this computer out of the test enviroment, however for now, everything seems to be running like it should. To correct the issue, I downloaded Workbench from www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ and with the idea of permissions from Steve started digging around in the my.ini file. Well it wasn't permissions, however I noticed that the server wasn't bound to an IP. IP was set to "null" so I changed the bind IP and port forwarded in the router, and all seems to be good.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know if my solution is the most secure however if does work. Please see my last post for information about my fix.